# Javascript - How to work around with "this" inside ES6 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

If i have the following approach:

```
element.addEventListener('click', foo)

const fooList = {
 1: new barClass().function1,
 2: new barClass().function2,
 3: new barClass().function3,
 ....
}

const foo = (bar) => {
 foobar = bar.innerText;
 let hasFunctionInList = fooList[foobar ];
 if (hasFunctionInList) fooList[foobar ]()
}
```

When i am inside the class, what can i do different to refer to the class as this?:

```
class barClass {
 function1 () {}
 function2 () {
 ** this.function1() ** // in this case "this" doesn't stands for the class barClass, and gives me an error "this.function1 is not a function"
}
 function3 () {}
}
```

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are actually trying to accomplish.  It appears you're misusing a class and methods on the class.  But, to help further, you need to back up several steps and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve because this approach looks wrong.

Comment: And, you don't "work-around" `this` in class methods.  You pass it in when you call the method with `obj.method()`.

Comment: It also appears that in your construction of `fooList`, you're creating objects and then throwing them away only so you can get the method.  There's no point in doing that.  You either need the object in which case you need to save it or you don't need the object in which case you should be using plain functions of static methods.  One or the other.

Comment: As an event listener, `foo` is passed an `Event` object as its argument. Perhaps `foobar = event.target.innerText;`, after renaming  `foo`'s argument to `event`, is how clicked text should be accessed.

Comment: @traktor it was a typo, thanks for letting me know.
selbie and trincot answered with everything i needed to know to search a bit more and find the problem i was facing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways. One is to create function references that are explicitly bound to the correct `this`:

```
const instance = new barClass();
const fooList = {
 1: () => instance.function1(),
 2: () => instance.function2(),
 3: () => instance.function3(),
 ....
}
```

Another solution, is to specify `this` explicitly at the time of the call:

```
const instance = new barClass();

// ...
let func = fooList[foobar];
if (func) func.call(instance);
```

Note that you have an error in the event handler. An event handler does not get the element as argument, but an event object. Either reference `this` for referencing the element (but then it must be a `function`), or take the `target` property of the argument:

```
const foo = (e) => {
   foobar = e.target.innerText;
   // ...
}
```

As mentioned in comments, in your version of the code, you create instances, but don't keep a reference to those. Moreover, your code suggests that you want each function to act on a *different* instance. Although your question does not reveal what the bigger picture is, with what we *can* see, there is no clear reason to use a class at all. You should probably just use plain functions without a class.

Comment: Yeah, but this `new barClass().function1` does not make much sense since they aren't even attempting to save or use the object in any way.  It appears like the OP perhaps has static methods and doesn't need an object at all.  I really think you ought to insist on a clearer question before jumping at guesses.

Comment: This is not a guess. It answers their question. But you are right that they are probably misusing a class for what could be static functions, or a module, ...etc. They certainly misuse the term "class" for when they mean "instance" (but this is a common misuse). I was about to comment about all this, but you already placed that comment, so I put my vote on it. You'll have noticed that I didn't repeat that `new barClass().function1` in my answer...

Comment: trincot and @jfriend, thanks for poiting the misuse, i will study more about the topic

Answer (score 2):

Classic way is to use bind:

```
const fooList = {};

let bar = new barClass();
let func = barClass.function1;
fooList[1] = func.bind(bar);

bar = new barClass();
func = bar.function2;
fooList[2] = func.bind(bar);
```

...

Or use arrow syntax in ES6:

```
const fooList = {};
let bar = new barClass();
fooList[1] = () => barClass.function1();

bar = new barClass();
fooList[2] = () => barClass.function2();
```